# Virtual Particles and Quantum Brownian Motion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, virtual-particles, brownian-motion

Does the frequency of virtual particles (creation/annihilation) match with nucleus random paths - known as Quantum Brownian Motion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my knowledge goes, the creation and annihilation of virtual particles are just a bookkeeping method for physicists when they model particle interactions. That is, virtual particles aren't actually particles, and it's thus nonsensical to describe the frequency of their creation/annihilation.

[This website here](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/) explains the concept of virtual particles well.

Comment: So what is the cause of the nucleus random path?

Comment: NB: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Virtual particles are a real phenomenon that impact our physical world.  Hawking Radiation is based on virtual particles that become separated at the event horizon of black holes.  The virtual pairs become real particles due to the extreme curvature of space-time in the gravitational fields of black holes.  The conversion of virtual particles to separated real particles represents  thermodynamic leakage from the black holes into normal space

Comment: I wouldnt really call Hawking radiation "a real phenomenon that impact our physical world" since as of yet there is not real experimental verification.

Comment: Hi Tim. Virtual particles are a computational device used in perturbative quantum field theory. If we ever come up with a non-perturbative approach there is no reason to suspect this will use the concept of virtual particles. In Hawking radiation the particle-antiparticle pair is just a metaphor. For the details [see this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251385/an-explanation-of-hawking-radiation/252236#252236).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).