# Has anyone mathematically proven the existence of Hawking Radiation yet?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

A little side question, can someone please explain to me how quantum and relativity would have an influence on this theory.

Comment: That's an odd phrasing.  Typically one does not prove existence in reality via mathematical proofs.  In fact, such a theoretical proof was exactly what Hawking put forth in 1974 when he published the idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An explanation of Hawking Radiation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251385/)

Comment: Not taking into account the issues with the phrasing in this question, I am pretty sure that Hawking did :)