# How do you know that the CMB radiation is not caused by the Unruh effect?

Tags: cosmology

"The Unruh effect (also known as the Fulling–Davies–Unruh effect) is the prediction that an accelerating observer will observe a thermal bath, like blackbody radiation, whereas an inertial observer would observe none." (Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect)

Since the CMB is observed to be a black body radiation at a temperature of 2.7K then, could it be due the Unruh effect instead of the accepted inflation model? (The Unruh effect would also explain the apparent homogeneity of the CMB radiation.) We also observe that the CMB show anisotropy. There is an apparent anisotropy due to our relative motion to the CMB, does this rule out the Unruh effect?

Answer (score 8):

The Unruh temperature is $$T=\frac{\hbar}{2\pi c k_B} a = 4.06\times 10^{-21} a. $$ To get a 2.7K temperature you hence need an acceleration of $6.6\times 10^{20}$ m/s$^2$. That is not observed: at that rate of expansion there would not be much structure in the universe, and besides it would tend to tear apart matter.

Comment: Could this acceleration be due to the dark energy, causing expansion of space? Or gravitational forces would not be strong enough to keep matter together in this case?

Comment: That acceleration would accelerate an object near you to nearly lightspeed in a fraction of a second. It would be *noticeable*.