# How come bigger black holes lose energy slower?

Tags: energy, black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation, virtual-particles

My understanding of Hawking radiation is probably extremely lackluster but from my understanding, two virtual particles pop into existence just like anywhere in the universe. Except due to the extreme gravitational influence of the black hole one particle escapes at *c* and the other is pulled in overtime this causes the black hole to lose mass.

So this event can only take place at the event horizon but from my understanding supermassive black holes radiate away much slower than smaller black holes (the extreme mass difference aside.)

How come supermassive black holes radiate away at a slower rate than small black holes despite having more surface areas?

And if the particle escapes and doesn't destroy each other how come this doesn't create infinite energy?

Comment: See [An explanation of Hawking Radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251385/an-explanation-of-hawking-radiation) for what actually happens in Hawking radiation

Comment: @JohnRennie Literally one second before I submitted my answer. Ah well, it is a duplicate, and your answer there is basically a better version of mine anyway ;)