# The change in mass of a black hole do to Hawking Radiation

Tags: black-holes, mass, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

Hawking radiation which is the result of virtual particles, which are always created in pairs,(particle/antiparticle) near enough to the event horizon of a black hole, that one of the pair falls in allowing its partner to escape. Why doesn't this phenomenon add mass to the black hole?

Comment: I have presented this argument on Quora a number of times, and the answers are  creative attempts to allow the particle that falls in to have negative energy; but the reasoning behind the negative mass particle always being the one that falls in, never made sense.

Comment: The particle that doesn't fall in is observable, so it can't have negative energy.

Comment: Do either of the pair of virtual particles actually have negative mass? Or do they just both receive energy enough to exist for a brief moment, as a quantum fluctuation?

Comment: The outgoing radiation persists. The outgoing virtual particle becomes real due to four-momentum from the gravitational field, just like the energy used to make W/Z bosons, Higgs bosons etc. visible in particle accelerators.

Comment: Related: [An explanation of Hawking Radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251385). The popular picture of Hawking radiation recited in the OP is just a *popular picture*. It is *not* how Hawking radiation is actually derived. The answers to the linked question give a taste of how it is actually derived and of where the popular picture comes from. Some popular pictures have at least a little bit of explanatory power, but this one seems to have mostly confusatory power.