# Wrist watch close to a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, event-horizon, observers

The article in the source below says,

> "As you get closer to a black hole, the flow of time slows down..."

I am trying to understand this whole time slowing down with the following thought experiment/question:

How would a regular wrist watch respond to getting closer to a black hole? Does it literally tick slower? Do the digits on a digital wrist watch that is closer to a black hole have its digits change very slowly?

( I come from an Electrical Engineering background. Would very much appreciate it, if at all possible, if you can please answer me using my background as a reference )

Sources:
https://lweb.cfa.harvard.edu/seuforum/bh_whatare.htm

Comment: Depends on who is looking at the watch. If you're the one wearing the watch, it ticks the same. If you're watching from far away, it ticks slower.

Comment: Think of the watch participating in the process that is the black hole. The process that is the watch slows down because it is interrupted by the process that is the black hole.

Comment: @shawn_halayka So is it safe to assume that the electronics, transistors, crystal oscillators etc in the watch somehow realize that they are close to a black hole and start "working" slower?

Comment: @shawn_halayka How do the electronics, electrical components "know" that they should work slower?

Comment: Mars, watch is "forced" to participate in the black hole's process, leaving less time for the watch's process. Are you familiar with Einstein's light clock?

Comment: @MarsSojourner in the same way that your body "knows" to fall down if you walk off a cliff on a planet with gravity.

Comment: We are talking about gravitational time dilation here, but there is also kinematic time dilation. Imagine a light clock -- two mirrors with a photon that bounces back and forth between them. Now accelerate the light clock transversely to the photon's path. Since the speed of light stays constant, it takes more time for the bounces to occur, because it takes more time for the photon to travel back and forth. Now, for gravitational time dilation, the light clock must participate in the black hole's process, so the internal process (photon emission) occurs less frequently.

Comment: Both gravitational and kinematic time dilation occur at the same time. That is, you can calculate the precession of the perihelion of Mercury's orbit, which is proportional to 3GM: two parts gravitational time dilation, one part kinematic time dilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean when you say "does it literally tick slower". More specifically, does it tick slower in comparison with what?

#### The Thought Experiment: what happens when you fall down a black hole?

Let us first assume that you are falling alone on the black hole for whatever reason. Do you notice anything weird with your watch? No, you do not. As mentioned in other answers, time has literally slowed down, and that applies to yourself, not only to your watch.

On the other hand, suppose you jumped off a spaceship and the crew over at the spaceship are monitoring you. In order to do this, they equipped you with a device that sends a radio signal whenever your wristwatch ticks. Hence, you are sending them a signal per second. What do they notice as you get closer to the black hole?

At first, they will not notice anything strange. They'll keep receiving signals at intervals of roughly one second, for the effects are quite small while you both are somewhat far from the black hole and close to each other. As you go near the black hole, they'll notice your signals are taking longer to come in. Instead of receiving one signal per second, they are receiving one signal every two seconds, eventually one signal every three seconds, and so on. In other words, your watch is ticking slower with respect to the crew over at the spaceship.

This effects gets stronger and stronger as you get close to the black hole. If someone from the crew takes a look at you through the window, they'll notice you are also getting redder, due to an effect known as [gravitational redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift) (in short, the light that's being reflected by your body loses energy as it moves away from the black hole, and light losing energy means light color getting shifted to the red). Eventually, this redshift effect gets so strong they can no longer see you (light has been shifted to the infrared, which our eyes can't see) and when they took a look at your signal (the frequency of which has also been changing due to the same reason) they'll notice the intervals have become so large they are no longer receiving your "messages" anymore. In spite of that, they've never seen you falling into the black hole, only getting closer and closer.

What about you? Did you get into the black hole? Yes. Within finitely many ticks of your clock, you will get into the black hole (and there will be nothing particularly shocking once you get into it, there is no sign saying "Welcome to the black hole!" nor any experiment you can perform locally to decide where is the black hole boundary). Hence, for you, time hasn't slowed down, and everything seems just as normal as ever. Nevertheless, if you pick a telescope and peek at a clock on the spaceship you jumped from, you will notice their clock seems to be running ridiculously fast.

It is in this sense that time slows down in a black hole. The particular mechanism of the clock does not matter: it is time itself that is slowing down, not just the clock. Hence, no one can perceive the effect locally, one has to compare their own wristwatch with a clock somewhere else to notice time is slowing down for them.

#### How do clocks know they should slow down close to a black hole?

This is in fact a consequence of the fact that gravity is just a manifestation of spacetime curvature. Space and time are actually a single entity which can bend and stretch and so on, and the consequences of this bending and stretching are what we call gravity. The clocks don't know they should tick slower in the same way you don't voluntarily move slower when you are in strong gravitational fields. As far as you, or the clock, are concerned, you are behaving as usual. The tricky thing is that "behaving as usual" has different meanings depending on where you are in spacetime.

I'll add another paragraph reinforcing this point because it is really important: it is not the watch that slows down, it is time itself. It doesn't matter what the watch is made of, it doesn't matter whether it is digital or analogue, or if it consists of you [counting periods of radiation of a Caesium-133 atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second), or if it consists of
[counting how many times a beam of light has reflected on a pair of mirrors](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_clock), or if you are measuring time with your heartbeat, or if you are clapping in regular intervals, or if you are repeatedly listening to your favorite song and counting how many times it has played. In every situation the effects are going to be the exact same because it is not the watch or the mechanism that is being slowed down with respect to the clock at the spaceship, it is time itself.

The fact that time runs differently in different regions of spacetime is, quite literally, the *cause* of gravity. This is beautifully discussed and illustrated on the PBS Spacetime video [*Does Time Cause Gravity?*](https://youtu.be/UKxQTvqcpSg).

Comment: By 'tick slower', I meant to ask if the second hand on a wrist watch's dial would move from one digit to the next after a long time.

Comment: @MarsSojourner It depends on who is looking. If you are wearing the wrist watch, it will move in the regular rate. If someone is looking at the wrist watch from a distance (for example, with a telescope), they will see the dial moving from one digit to the next more slowly than usual. 

Yes, it is weird.

Comment: So who is living in reality? Is it the person wearing the watch who sees the watch handle move at a regular rate or the person looking at the wrist watch from a distance? Or is reality also relative? LOL.

Comment: @MarsSojourner The thing is that the concept of time is relative. Both are experiencing reality, they just see time passing in different ways. Suppose, for example, I were to ask you how far away is São Paulo. I would answer roughly 30 km, you would likely answer something different (assuming you are not in Brazil). Which one of us is right? Both. The reason we received two different answers is because we asked two different questions

Comment: The source below says, "Time also slows as gravity gets stronger...." Since every spot in the Universe is influenced by the gravity of some object or another, is there a theoretical spot in the Universe where clocks tick the proper amount? In other words, how can we be sure of the correct time, since it seems that every clock will experience dilation because of some random object's gravity acting upon it. Source:https://astronomy.com/magazine/news/2018/09/black-holes-test-the-limits-of-einsteins-relativity

Comment: @MarsSojourner That's the thing about relativity: there is no correct time. Time is always a relative concept. You can only talk about time if you say who is measuring it. There is no "universal clock", there is no "correct time".

Just as there is no correct distance to São Paulo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132718/discussion-between-nickolas-alves-and-mars-sojourner).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes, a wrist watch, regardless of if it is mechanical or electrical, runs slower near a black hole.  It also runs slower near the Earth, or the Sun, or any planet or even dark matter than it does in "open space".

All of these things slow down time.  But it is vital for you to understand that if you are wearing the wrist watch, then you would not notice the slowing of time because you are also subject to that same slowing of time. It is ONLY if you are looking at the wrist watch from a very far distance that you will notice that it is running slower than the time at your location.  And in answer to your other question, everything including every electrical circuit that you can think of also runs at that slower time.

This has two major implications,  first; many scientists believe that this time dilation is responsible for gravity. This is the warping of spacetime that you have heard about. That is, things fall to where time runs slowest. So things fall to the Earth, or the moon, or the sun or a black hole because time runs slower on the surface of these than it does in space.

Second, if you want to travel to the future, the process is very simple.  If you can get yourself to a black hole and orbit it for a few years in your own time, you can come back to Earth in the distant future to visit your great great great grandchildren.

Comment: The source below says, "Time also slows as gravity gets stronger...." Since every spot in the Universe is influenced by the gravity of some object or another, is there a theoretical spot in the Universe where clocks tick the proper amount? In other words, how can we be sure of the correct time, since it seems that every clock will experience dilation because of some random object's gravity acting upon it. 

Source:
https://astronomy.com/magazine/news/2018/09/black-holes-test-the-limits-of-einsteins-relativity#:~:text=Time%20also%20slows%20as%20gravity,slowly%20than%20those%20farther%20away.

Comment: @MarsSojourner  You are correct that every spot in the universe is influenced more or less by gravity, so there is no spot where time runs without this influence.  But it is very easy to calculate that time flow since the influence of the Earth or the moon is so small.     As for your quote that "time also slows as gravity gets stronger..."  I would say that the quote has it backwards; gravity is the warping of spacetime, mainly time.   So it is time dilation that establishes gravity, and not gravity that influences time dilation.

Comment: @MarsSojourner : There is no universally applicable "correct" time, any more than there is a universally "correct" distance north. For example, if there is a mountain north of your current location and you walk a mile due north, you may end up high in the air and only 0.5 miles closer to the north pole, relative to where you started. This could be considered "north dilation" due to the curvature of local space (the mountain).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say a capacitor has energy 10 J. To make that energy do work for us we may tie the capacitor on a string and then lower it towards a black hole. The electric energy does work when it pulls on the string. Work done when the capacitor is at the lowest possible position is 10 J.

A voltmeter with long wires will show that voltage of the capacitor is decreasing when it is being lowered. From that we may conclude that the capacitance is increasing.

Same story with an inductor:

Let's say an inductor has energy 10 J. To make that energy to do work for us we may tie the inductor on a string and then lower it towards a black hole. The electric energy does work when it pulls on the string. Work done when the inductor is at the lowest possible position is 10 J.

An ammeter with long wires will show that current of the inductor is decreasing when it is being lowered. From that we may conclude that the inductance is increasing.

Now finally as we have established that inductance and capacitance are inversely proportional to gravitational potential we can calculate the frequency of a LC-circuit near a black hole: $1/\sqrt{L_{down}C_{down}}$

The zero point of gravitational potential must be set at the event horizon for this to work.

Answer (score -2):

The watch becomes assimilated by the black hole. The watch’s process is overcome by the black hole's process. The watch is forced to participate in the black hole’s process. At the event horizon, the assimilation is complete. The watch’s tick rate is related to the gravitational time dilation.

You could say that the probability of a process occurring is equal to $\sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{rc^2}}$