# Might the tiny Hawking radiation from our cosmic event horizon (CEH) be additive, since my CEH is not your CEH?

Tags: cosmology, event-horizon, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

Concerning our cosmic event horizon, an interesting question arises from the seemingly innocent statement, "My cosmic event horizon is not your cosmic event horizon."  Ie: Since 'you' and 'I' are not in
the same place and the universe is isotropic around each one of us, and we're separated by some distance $r$, then *in principle*, our two CEHs are also separate (offset) from one another by some distance,
on the order of $r$. This implies two distinct CEHs... each of which is sending Hawking radiation (HR) into our universe.  The question then is, are these two distinct HRs additive? If so, into how many ways can our ~de Sitter universe be divided up into $N$ distinct 'cells', each of which is operationally at the center of its own physically distinguishable CEH?  Where each such CEH is generating its own additive HR?

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not additive. The reason is the origin of these sorts of effects. For simplicity, I'll treat our Universe as being exactly de Sitter.

Firstly, I should notice that the thermal radiation on de Sitter spacetime created by means of quantum field theoretic effects is not due to the Hawking effect (which occurs in a collapsing star spacetime), but rather due to the related [Unruh effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect), which occurs in spacetimes with a geometric structure known as a "bifurcate Killing horizon". These two effects are fairly often mistaken, especially because one can derive the Unruh effect in Schwarzschild spacetime (a non-rotating, uncharged black hole) in a manner way simpler than one can derive the Hawking effect. Here are the main differences:

- the Unruh effect concerns spacetimes with a notion of time-translation symmetry and predicts that some observer sees a thermal spectrum of particles *all around them*. For a black hole, this means there's also particles coming in from infinity. Rotating black holes do not exhibit the Unruh effect due to technical reasons.
- the Hawking effect concerns the spacetime of a star that collapses to a black hole. In this case, the thermal particles come only from the black hole. Rotating black holes do exhibit the Hawking effect.

#### Non-Technical Version

The thermal spectrum depends on the observer. The temperature coming from each horizon is not observer-independent, but rather is the temperature measured by the observer with that horizon. Since each horizon gives rise to a notion of temperature in a different sense (each one corresponding to a particular observer), they don't add up. The reason is because the temperature is due to emission of particles by the horizon, and *particles are not an observer-independent concept* (I discussed the reason behind this in a not-so-technical way in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/700028/168783)).

In short, the temperatures don't add up because they are different notions of temperature. Each CEH leads to the notion of temperature associated to the observer that has that particular CEH.

#### Technical Version

I'll first state the effect in more technical terms, then discuss it more physically, without all the technicalities. The short statement is that if an observer's worldline follows the orbit of a [Killing vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) generating such a horizon and the quantum field is in a symmetric state with respect to the isometry generated by this vector field, then the observer experiences the state as a thermal state.

Let me write this is a different way. Suppose you have a symmetry in your spacetime. For example, in Minkowski spacetime, we have boosts in the $x$ direction, as an example. Consider the transformation on the spacetime when you boost it with some velocity $v$. Each point is mapped to some different point. The way this happens in Minkowski spacetime is that, as we continuously vary $v$, some points describe a timelike trajetory (those with $|x| > |t|$). some describe a spacelike trajectory ($|x| < |t|$), and some describe a null trajectory ($|x|=|t|$). This sort of behaviour is, roughly, what we call a bifurcate Killing horizon. The Killing horizons are the surfaces in which the trajectories are null ($x = \pm t$), and the "bifurcate" is because it bifurcates into two horizons.

Suppose now one observer is following one of these trajectories. This is the case, for example, for accelerating observers. What the Unruh effect predicts then is that if the quantum field is in a state invariant under these trajectories (for example, the Minkowski vacuum), then such an observer will see this state as a thermal state. Hence, accelerated observers see a thermal bath in the Minkowski vacuum, which inertial observers see as having no particles at all, and consider to be at vanishing temperature. This is known as the Unruh effect in flat spacetime.

Notice that different observers have different notions of what is going on. It is important to point out that they disagree on the temperature and they disagree on whether there are particles on the spacetime, but they do agree on the quantum state of the field. There is nothing paradoxical about this, because quantum field theory is a theory of fields, not of particles. It simply means that what is measured by an inertial thermometer is not the same thing measured by an accelerated thermometer. [This answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/700028/168783) discusses more about the relativity of the notion of particle in Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetimes.

Now, de Sitter spacetime. In this situation, for every timelike geodesic we can find a Killing vector field with those properties. In other words, for any free falling observer, we have such a construction like the one I just mentioned in Minkowski spacetime. Hence, all inertial observers in de Sitter spacetime experience the field (if it is in a symmetric state) as being in a thermal state, with temperature given by $T = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\Lambda}{3}}$. These effects are not additive, because the temperature each observer measures is due to their own notion of particle. While I have a CEH and you have another one, we also have different notions of particles. What you call a particle and what I call a particle are different things, and hence each of us only perceives as temperature those particles that we see due to our own CEH.

For more information on these topics, I recommend Wald's [*Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime and Black Hole Thermodynamics*](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/Q/bo3684008.html), which discusses the Unruh effect in de Sitter spacetime on Sec. 5.3. There is also a [seminal paper by Gibbons and Hawking on the matter](https://doi.org/10.1103%2Fphysrevd.15.2738). I quote a phrase from their abstract:

> The derivation of these results involves abandoning the idea that particles should be defined in an observer-independent manner.

Comment: As a remark, it seems Wikipedia calls this an instance of the "[Gibbons–Hawking effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbons%E2%80%93Hawking_effect)", probably after the paper by Gibbons and Hawking that I mentioned. Wald calls it an instance of the Unruh effect in curved spacetimes.

Comment: For Alves:  I read your answer, which is way above my pay grade. The wikipedia entry on the "Unruh Effect" says the following: “..The Rindler spacetime has a horizon, and locally any non-extremal black hole horizon is Rindler. So the Rindler spacetime gives the local properties of black holes and cosmological horizons. It is possible to rearrange the metric restricted to these regions to obtain the Rinder metric.[10] The Unruh effect would then be the near-horizon form of Hawking radiation…”  The last sentence seems to say there is no operational distinction between Unruh and Hawking effects.

Comment: @user86742 That is a common misconception, and Wald's text clearly states in Chap 5 that is is wrong. The origin of the effects is a bit different and they are physically very different: the Unruh effect for a black hole has particles coming in from infinity, while the Hawking effect only has particles coming in from the black hole.

Comment: @user86742 As soon as I can I'll edit the answer to add a less technical description. It seems I assumed more requisites than I should have in this version. I apologize for that

Comment: @user86742 Please let me know if the new version is clearer. If it isn't, I'll gladly edit it again =)

Comment: I deleted a comment on the question, after reading Nickolas Alves' good answer, which implies that I'd misunderstood the varied nature of "observers" in GR.

Comment: Thanks.  This’ll take time to absorb.  For your amusement: Iff I'd been right, assuming the smallest cell is 10^-15 m (Ie:  The irreducible limit of r= Ru^(1/3)lpl^(2/3) of the universe taking its own measure; see Lloyd/Ng 4-1-07 Sciam), the total HR lum. would sum to on the order of c^5/G.
Ie: lpl=Planck length, Ru^3/r^3 ~ 10^123 = N, then N*Lu ~ 10^50 Joules/sec., Lu = ‘HR’ luminosity per -individual- CEH.  For what it's not worth ;-).

Comment: @Níckolas Alves wrote: *"Rotating black holes do not exhibit the Unruh effect due to technical reasons."* - if nonrotating BHs do, slowly rotating ones have to as well, there has to be a continuous transistion. Do you mean maximally rotating ones, or that the frame dragging doesn't cause an extra Unruh effect?

Comment: The units you set to 1 were c=h=k=1 (speed of light, Planck and Boltzmann constant), so T=√(Λ/3)ch/k=Hh/k=1e-28K, correct?

Comment: @Yukterez No. Rotating black holes do not have the Unruh effect at all. There is no quantum state in the Kerr spacetime that is both stationary and Hadamard (I think Kay and Wald showed this, or refer to it, in a famous 1991 paper). Since this is the state necessary for the Unruh effect, the Unruh effect does not happen at all for a Kerr black hole. The Hawking effect still occurs.

Comment: @Yukterez Your calculation seems correct, although I didn't check the units very carefully. The final result is at that scale (I actually got 10^-29 on a quick calculation using some Wikipedia values, but I might have made a mistake somewhere)

Comment: I don't know about the Hadamard, but what about the limit when the black hole spin is only an infinitesimal, that should give the same result as Schwarzschild even though the spin is not exactly 0, so if there really is no Unruh at all even for slowly rotating Kerr then there shouldn't be one for Schwarzschild either, otherwise the limit wouldn't match

Comment: In De Sitter space the temperature seems to be T=√(Λ/3)cℏ/(2πk)=Hℏ/(2πk)=2.6e-30K, with the reduced Planck constant and an extra 2π in the denominator, [here](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/gravity-lectures.pdf) at 7.17 they divide by 2π again although setting ℏ=1, the T=2.6e-30K should be the correct result

Comment: @Yukterez Indeed, I missed a $2\pi$ factor in the temperature (I actually quoted the surface gravity instead). Thanks for pointing it out! I fixed the typo.

Comment: @Yukterez Yes, even a black hole with infinitesimal rotation would not present the Unruh effect. This is a difficulty in modeling real situations, not with the prediction itself. The limit does not need to be continuous, and there are other examples in physics of situations with non-continuous limit (e.g. the zero viscosity limit in fluid dynamics). Notice also that Schwarzschild spacetime has spherical symmetry, but Kerr spacetime does not, even for infinitesimal angular momentum.

Comment: See Sec. 6.4 of [Kay and Wald's 1991 paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(91)90015-E).